# How can I pass a param for a function inside my React Native Function Component?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-component

I have a Picker component that is populated with data from a local realm database, the component has a function that receives the name of the database schema as a param. What I want to do is, instead of writing the name of the schema inside the function, to receive it as a prop or a param, so I can use the same component to show pickers with different information.

This is my code:

```
const PickerDB: React.FC<PickerProps> = (props) => {
    const [data, setData] = useState([]);

    async function loadData() {
        setData(await GetDataFromDB('source')); // this is what I want to modify
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        loadData();
    }, [])

    let values = data.map((data) => {
        return (
            <Picker.Item
                label={data.description}
                value={data.id}
                key={data.id}
            />
        )
    })

    return (
        <Picker
            selectedValue={props.selectedValue}
            style={{ height: 45, width: "70%" }}
            onValueChange={props.onValueChange}
        >
            {values}
        </Picker>
    );
```

I need to create my component using `React.FC<PickerProps>` because of other functions inside my app.

I would like to use my component like this:

```
<PickerDB source={'schemaName'} />
```

Comment: `<PickerDB source={'schemaName'} />` will store a prop source in the PickerDB, which you simple can access with `props.source` within your `fetch`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what you need to do:

```
async function loadData(source) {
  setData(await GetDataFromDB(source)); // this is what I want to modify
}

useEffect(() => {
  if (props.source) {
    loadData(props.source);
  }
}, [props.source]);
```

Comment: I have already tried this, what i can't do is make my component receive the source, if i try `<PickerDB source={'schemaName'} />` i get this error: Property 'source' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & PickerProps & { children?: ReactNode; }'.

Comment: @GuilhermeMoretto This is the 100% the answer. your error is a typescript error and you need to add `source: string` to the `PickerProps` and you good to go

Comment: Ok, thank you. Can you tell me or show me how i can do it?

Comment: Do you have access to `PickerProps`?

Comment: I created an interface and extended PickerProps, then added the source, thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: @GuilhermeMoretto That's it, good job, Cheers